# Jquery replaceWith: how to target a specific Div

Tags: jquery, replacewith

My html has several DIV:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

In my Jquery script I am trying to use replaceWith to replace a particular `<div>` with

```
<div>I'm new!</div>
```

However, I'm not able to target a particular Div. I only seem able to replace all `<div>` with this new div. I can also add a class or anything else to the div if necessary.

Comment: Show us your current code on how you are trying to target the divs. And you can format code with the curly brace icon in the editor.

Comment: jQuery has many possible selectors to use. It will benefit you to take some time and see what's available: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors You'll use *lots* of selectors when using jQuery. Selecting by ID is among the most basic. I'd also suggest taking a look [at some of the Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
$("#div1").replaceWith("<div>I'm new!</div>");
```

Have you tried it?

The jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for `replaceWith` explains this quite well.

Comment: Thanks! I did not find this example in their documentation. I saw: $('.second').replaceWith() and $("<div/>").replaceWith() and $("p").replaceWith(). Nothing using ID and the pound(hash) sign. Is there something basic that I am missing and that I should read first?

Comment: @dkgirl: You should definitely check out the CSS selector syntax (here it is from the horse's mouth: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) which is (simplifying a bit) what you can use in CSS. jQuery supports all that, and then some more: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors.

Comment: Awesome. I need this! Thanks Jon :)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

$("#div1") should grab the specific ID.